# ServiceStack OrmLite - database first & multiple primary keys

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have to work off an existing Db & would like to use ServiceStack's OrmLite.

Thus I have created Poco classes, using OrmLite T4 templates.

**ISSUE: I would like to save to a table which has multiple primary keys.**

```
 public partial class DbUserGroup
{
    [Required]
    public int Userid { get; set;} // this is a primary key
    [Required]
    public int Groupid { get; set;} // this is a primary key

    public int Ranking { get; set;}
    public bool Isprimary { get; set;}
}
```

Currently using Db.Save(userGroup) does not work. Is there any way of addressing this using ServiceStack's OrmLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding [PrimaryKey] to both properties.

```
public partial class DbUserGroup
{
    [Required]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Userid { get; set;} // this is a primary key

    [Required]
    [PrimaryKey]
     public int Groupid { get; set;} // this is a primary key

    public int Ranking { get; set;}
    public bool Isprimary { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this fails if there are more than two primary keys required

Answer (score 1):

Multiple primary keys don't exist. A multi-column primary key yes.
Please take a look on this link https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#limitations

As it said

> A potential workaround to support tables with multiple primary keys is to create an auto generated Id property that returns a unique value based on all the primary key fields

Comment: However, given that it is a database first approach (I do not have control over db structure), the suggested workaround "create an auto generated Id property that returns a unique value based on all the primary key fields" is not appropriate. This results in OrmLite expecting an Id property in the Db?

Comment: This is not mandatory. You can use Id property (get only) and add the [Ignore] attribute to it to avoid mapping error.